# Question on battery basics (I'm confused and not sure how to state my question)

Tags: voltage, batteries, amperage

I'm new to the mathematics behind the electrical engineering and quite confused. I have done some searching around and haven't found anything, probably because I'm asking the wrong question.

On a 9V battery, it says '9V'. **What does that mean?** Does it mean it always has a voltage of 9V (Around that since the battery drains), or that up to 9V can be pulled?

I guess this also hooks into another question: If you have an LED in a circuit, **What decides how much voltage it gets?** Does the LED limits the amount of power going through it, or does the battery force a particular voltage and current through it, which can be modified by resistors to lower the amp and up the volt?

Sorry if I am completely asking wrong.

Comment: 9V is the nominal voltage you would measure at the terminals. If you draw too much current that terminal voltage will fall due to internal resistance. You seem to be confused between voltage and  current. The basic formula is V = IR (Ohm's law).

Comment: @Jim Dearden Yes, I am. If something said 12v 1A, could I put in 1v 12A? Does the power put in only matter on the watt?

Comment: @Evan_K2014 You can put in a certain amount of voltage (the normal situation), or a certain amount of current (a very rare situation, but possible), but not both at the same time. If you control one then the other is decided for you. This applies to all electronic devices.

Comment: LEDs are not good devices to start with. Begin with lightbulbs, they're much more straightforward.

Comment: I was going to write a LED how-to, to answer your second question.  But actually I think you're better googling, because there are literally thousands of LED how-to explanations online. All of them need you to have grasped basic Ohm's Law first though.  After that, a good starting point is https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/light-emitting-diodes-leds

Comment: You've been given good answers, so I guess your misunderstandings are now solved. I won't elaborate on that, but still wanted to comment on the *"how to state my question"* part. You did very good. This is indeed a basic question, but you very well stated what you understand, and at which exact point you start having doubts. People with this level of knowledge usually make inaccurate assumptions and then ask questions just a level too high, and it then makes it very difficult for answerers to understand at which point it became nonsense. You didn't do this mistake. +1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are over-thinking all this, and/or have some bad mental models. You also provide this dilemma: that it must either be "always has 9 V" or else "up to 9 V can be pulled." That's not the dilemma and I don't even know what you mean when you say "pulled."

A battery is based on some internal chemistry. There are some molecular ion potentials based upon some pretty basic physics which, luckily for us humans, means that a battery chemistry has the effect of providing a relatively stable voltage. You can even get a battery by sticking two dissimilar metal rods into different parts of a lemon, for example. (Not a "good" battery, though.)

Batteries that are designed to supply a voltage also have a "compliance current" specification for them. And sometimes, the specification will describe how well they work at several different currents: with low current situations lasting longer and high current situations lasting much shorter, over their useful lives.

When a battery is applied to a circuit (like an LED circuit), the battery's fresh chemistry setup tries to provide a roughly stable voltage to that circuit. But if the circuit requires too much current for the chemistry and physical design of the battery, then the voltage will droop. Sometimes, it will droop a whole lot, while still providing *some* current. Usually, batteries that are tied to a load that could use far more current than they can manage to supply, have their internal chemistry operating at such a pace that it impairs their lifetime of service, too. So it's important to stay within their designed specifications regarding the applied load.

A very simple way to visualize a chemical battery is to think of it as an ideal battery with a series resistor attached. In this way, if the circuit tries to draw too much current then this internal series resistor will "drop" some voltage before the circuit itself gets access to it. But this is just a very simple approximation. A real battery is much more complex and modeling them is an art of sorts.

But the basic idea is that a battery (or any practical voltage source) isn't perfect and has limitations. But designers depend upon the idea of a range of reasonable voltages when faced with a range of reasonable load currents. So, for example, I might design a circuit for a 9 V battery expecting no lower than 7.5 V and no more than 9.2 V from it over its lifetime of use. No, it won't ALWAYS provide 9 V. It will provide higher voltages early in its life and lower voltages later on as its chemistry gets used up. I have to decide how low I can accept, before my circuit stops working correctly. The lower I can manage, the longer the battery lasts. But the voltage also drops a lot more quickly as it gets near the end of its life, too. So I have to make a reasoned judgment about where to draw that line.

Comment: *"In this way, if the circuit tries to draw too much current then this internal series resistor will 'drop' some voltage before the circuit itself gets access to it."* This is one of the most straightforward analogies of the effects of secondary and tertiary current distribution effects in batteries I've ever seen. +1

Answer (score 4):

An ideal 9 volt supply has exactly 9 V output voltage independent of load -- whether you draw 1 mA or 1000 A, the voltage measured at the terminals will always be 9 V.  A 9 V battery is a reasonable approximation of this over some load range.  A fresh battery with no load will have approximately 9 V (actually slightly higher).  If you draw current, the voltage will be a little less (the battery has some internal resistance), and as the battery is depleted, the open-circuit voltage will drop.  If you try to draw too much current, the output voltage will drop well below 9 V.  However, this mode of operation is extremely inefficient, the battery will not last very long and will get quite hot.

Most power supplies are like this: they are designed to operate at some roughly constant voltage with current varying from zero up to some upper current limit.  The limit, and the variation of the output voltage with load current is part of the specifications for a power supply.

Its possible to make the opposite: a constant current source.  This is a supply designed to produce a constant current into a load, as long as the voltage drop does not get to high (e.g., the load resistance is less than some value).  These are quite commonly used as circuit elements, but very rarely used as a power supply.

Answer (score 2):

To answer ALL of your questions, you need to wrap your head around Ohm's law, in all of its forms. Given I = Current [amps], V = Voltage [volts] (more accurately called Electrical Potential), and R = Resistance [ohms], Ohm's Law states that I=V/R. Doing some math, it also states that V=IR and R=V/I. Look over all three of these as it applies to your circuit.

I=V/R: Given a fixed 9V source, then the resistance in a circuit (like a loop of wire with an LED) determines how much current flows.

V=IR: The voltage measured across a resistor, known as the "voltage drop" is the product of the resistance value and the current. In a simple circuit, the sum of all of the voltage drops adds up to the voltage being supplied, in this case by your battery.

In the real world, batteries are not perfect and neither is wire. If your battery was a perfect 9V source and copper was a perfect conductor, then hooking a loop of copper to your battery terminals would give I=V/R = 9V/0 Ohms = INFINITE current! In the real world, the copper wire and your battery have a small amount of internal resistance. So when you pass current through an LED circuit, your actual current I=V/Rtotal, where Rtotal = Rbatt (internal battery resistance) + Rload (your LED or other resistance element) + Rwire. In the real world, you are usually driving an LED with maybe a 20 ohm resistance, and your wire and battery resistances are MUCH smaller than that, so you ignore them and calculate your current based just on the LED resistance. Why go to the trouble of looking up your battery's internal resistance and calculating the wire resistance just so you can get your I=V/R calculation ABSOLUTELY PERFECT instead of "within 1%"?
But your battery is a chemical cell and its voltage does drop as it discharges. And if you hook it, or any other power source, up to a low enough resistance, then the current you are pulling through it will be so high that the internal resistance will start to matter, and you will lose voltage within your power supply because the voltage drop through the cell or power supply will be V=IR. Let's say you have a 9V battery with an internal resistance of 0.5 ohms (a made up number; I haven't looked it up). If your circuit has a 20 ohm load, current through the circuit is V/R = 9/(20 + .5) = .439 amps, which is just 2.5% less than the 0.45 amps you would calculate if you ignored the internal resistance. But if your circuit only has a 0.5 ohm load, then current through the circuit is I=V/R = 9V/(0.5 + 0.5) ohms = 9 amps, and the voltage drop through each component is V=IR = 9*0.5 = 4.5 volts. That's right, the battery loses 4.5 volts pushing those 9 amps THROUGH ITSELF, and produces only 4.5 volts at its terminals to drive the LED. In this case the LED would burn really bright and the battery would heat up and die pretty quickly.

In intuitive terms, think of a resistive circuit as a pump pushing water through a hose into a sump tank. The pressure in the line is the voltage, the flow rate is the current, and anything that blocks flow is resistance. Crimp off the hose and you have high pressure in the line but no water is flowing. Ease off the crimp and pressure remains high but some water flows. If you open the line up completely, the hose goes kind of slack due to loss of pressure; in the absence of any resistance, the pump starts dumping water through the system at low pressure. The bigger and stronger the pump, the better able it is to maintain pressure at higher and higher flow rates. Batteries and power supplies are the same way.

Answer (score 1):

From Ohm's Law using a Resistive voltage divider, one can determine any battery ESR by the incremental rise in some current with corresponding drop in voltage. This assumes some >5% minimum steady state load as initial state.
Of course a drop in 50% voltage matches the internal ESR but causes self heating.

These are not rigid specs but generally true for new fresh batteries.
Generally the larger the Ah capacity and size, the lower the ESR.
Small coin cells have very high ESR and thus rated for < 0.5mA.  Whereas the CR123A slightly larger than a AA has very stable 3.00V and lower ESR than I showed below.

[image: schematic]

Shown above is 1) Alkaline, 2) Lithium 3) Lithium and 4) Lithium Phospate (LiPO3) or LiPo

ALSO LED's can be modeled just like batteries above where the Vf depends on wavelength and the ESR depnds on chip size and Power rating, generally

Diode \$ ESR~_{[Ω]}= \frac{0.5 ~~to~~ 1}{Pd[W]}\$ at rated Vf@If (including ESR) when the diode is saturated.

Comment: Thank you for responding! I'll come back to this in a bit, it is too confusing right now ("I'm new to the mathematics behind electrical engineering").

Comment: I hope you know how to calculate a voltage divider RL/(RL+Rs) for load and series R source

Comment: What I mean by "I'm new" is that I haven't done much in electrical engineering in general. I don't know what you mean by 'voltage divider,' or 'SoC,' or 'ESR,' etc. If your claim is true, you have been doing electrical engineering for over 45 years. I'm still a HS student.

Comment: ok Ohm's Law is 1st step to Electrical understanding....if you want .. If a source has some resistance and load is the same it divides in half (1/(1+1)  for batteries we want it to regulate so the load much be at least 10x the source resistance.if not more  ( meaning resistance to current so less current flows and voltage drop is less

Comment: Ok that makes sense.